# Migrated Visual Studio Project not finding NuGet packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore

I am migrating an MVC ASP.NET Visual Studio 2010 project to Visual Studio 2019.

The Visual Studio 2010 project uses some old jQuery NuGet packages that I can't update to current ones due to time constraints and the numerous changes through out the project that doesn't fit into my current scope.

The migrated 2019 project shows a number of errors all relating to the NuGet packages:

```
NuGet Package restore failed for project MyWebProject: Unable to find version '3.2.0' of package 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax.3.2.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
  Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.            

NuGet Package restore failed for project MyWebProject: Unable to find version '2.1.1' of package 'jQuery'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'jQuery.2.1.1' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
  Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.        
...
...
...
```

In the Visual Studio 2019 project, when I view the NuGet Installed packages, I see the packages listed but with a message *Not available in this source*

According to the error messages, Visual Studio is looking for the packages in *C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages*; however it should be looking in a directory named "packages" that actually contains the packages.

I have placed the packages directory within the same directory as the project (but it would be better to put them in a common resource directory so that the team can find them when/if they are working on this project). I have also edited the *repositories.config* file within the packages directory to point to the *packages.config* file for the project.

I can restore all of this back to default if required.

Nothing I have done has helped me get past this problem.

How do I direct Visual Studio 2019 to use the packages that exist within a directory that is not the Program Files directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I direct Visual Studio 2019 to use the packages that exist
>   within a directory that is not the Program Files directory?

According to your error message: Please go `Tools=>Options=>Nuget Package Manager` to check your settings about Package sources.

Maybe you haven't checked the nuget.org as your package sources. Please check this settings:

[image]

In VS, when you click the `Restore Nuget Packages` option, it will search the packages `from available sources`. Most of the time the package which we need to restore comes from [Nuget Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/). Just like the `JQuery 2.1.1`, so by default we will set nuget.org as our necessary package sources.

I've checked if I uncheck the nuget.org then I got the same issue like yours.

So please:

1.Check the nuget.org as your package sources, if it not exists, just click the green `+` to create a new sources and set its source as `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

2.If the nuget.org exists with checked status, make sure its link is correct
In addition:

> however it should be looking in a directory named "packages" that
>   actually contains the packages.

If the `packages` folder you mean is the one locates in `Solution directory`: In my opinion, `Restore Nuget Package` doesn't mean `searching sources from the packages folder`, instead it will search packages from `available package sources` and install them to `packages folder` if something is missing in the `packages folder`.(for packages.config format)

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I wasn't looking in the right place at all! It didn't have the nuget.org source.